# Running older software on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, drivers, compatibility

I just received my new flashy pair of headphones (gaming) with a device driver installation disk. Now I usually just download the latest drivers from the manufacturer's website anytime I buy a new peripheral but since I didn't find a single trace of my headphones' device driver online, I thought I'll just install from the disk. The headphones have some features like 7.1 surround sound, Customizable lighting, and vibration so I guess a software install is essential.

However, whenever I try to run the setup given on the disk it pops up the error

> DON'T SUPPORT THIS PLATFORM.

Obviously compatibility issues. Tried running in compatibility mode for Win 8.1/8/7 but didn't work. Anyone got any ideas?

The headphones are Kotion Each G5200. They got USB interface btw. Also under playback devices my headphones get identified as speakers. I'm sure that messes stuff up...

P.S- Emailed Kotion. The email address they gave on their website, doesn't even exist. Great...

Comment: Have you just tried it without drivers installed? That model is supposed to have a "smart driver chip" in it so that plug-and-play is supposed to work. You may not need any drivers installed.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver yeah it does work. PnP is working just fine and I must say these headphones are great. I'd still, however, would want to see what the software has to offer. Because if this thing has customizable lighting, I doing it no matter what. Also, for some reason, my B&O equaliser isn't working with this. My laptop has B&O audio but since over USB it behaves like a different sound card itself I think the software should offer me an equaliser as well.

Comment: I suppose that's what the manufacturer intended by making it have a smart driver chip. Due to its vibration ability, colored LEDs and other effects, it has to act like its own sound card. As to the loss of the software, and whatever it might have offered, that's part of the hassle of using older hardware with newer systems. I lost most of the functionality of my HP scanner between XP and Vista, never to be seen again. :( I keep a dual boot, minimal install, of XP just for that purpose. When I get a new MOBO I'm gonna loose my 5¼ drive too. <tears>

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver This means that I won't be able to run that software on my PC. Well, that ain't good, I lost out on my equaliser and potential customization. But the software does support Win 8.1 and Mac even so it seems strange to me that how it isn't  working on Win10. Maybe I could try installing it on a PC with Win8.1 and then copy the installed files over to my PC??

Answer (score 0):

Well seems like the software isn't gonna install on Win10. I did, though, install it on a Win7 PC to see what the software had to offer. Surprisingly, there wasn't much difference between audio quality before or after installing the driver. Also, the software only had controls to mute the headphone and speaker and to adjust volume only. No equaliser, no customizable lighting (sobs).

So I just fine tuned my headset to my liking using APO equaliser and its working pretty fine!